# C++ Poco Отправка post запроса

Tags: c++, post, poco

Пытаюсь отправить запрос post но не получается, Get приходит а post нет.

С++

```
 #include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
    #include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
    #include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
    #include <Poco/StreamCopier.h>
    #include <Poco/Path.h>
    #include <Poco/URI.h>
    #include <Poco/Exception.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace Poco::Net;
    using namespace Poco;
    using namespace std;



    std::string Post(std::string url)
    {
    try
      {
        // prepare session
        URI uri(url.c_str());
        HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

        //Подготовить путь
        string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
        //
        if (path.empty()) path = "/";

        // send request
        HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
        session.sendRequest(req);

        // get response
        HTTPResponse res;
        //if(res.getStatus() == 200)

        std::string resR = "";
        // print response
        istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
      //  StreamCopier::copyStream(is, cout);
        char A[255];
        is.getline(A,255);
        resR += A;
        return resR;
    }
      catch (Exception &ex)
      {
        //cerr << ex.displayText() << endl;
        return "";
      }//
      return "";

    }







    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

      std::string url = "http://autorization.com/tttt/g.php?Dat=test";

      Post(url);
      return 0;
    }
```

php

```
 <?php
    file_put_contents('t/1.txt',$_POST['Dat']);
    file_put_contents('t/2.txt',$_GET['Dat']);
    ?>
```

ps Отправляемые данные числовой массив объёмом 10mb в виде текста.

Comment: В коде не видно (скорее пропущено) передаваемые данные.

Comment: Так в этом и проблема, я не знаю как и куда вставить данные для post запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Данные POST-запроса передаются в "теле". Поэтому URL должен быть такого вида: http://autorization.com/tttt/g.php

Тело отправляется примерно так:

```
// send request
    HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.setKeepAlive(true);
    req.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
    req.setContentType("text/plain");

    std::string body("Dat=Base64NumericArrayString");
    
    session.sendRequest(req) << body;
```

Установка ChunkedTransferEncoding делает ненужным указание длины сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо проверю если все работает помечю как правильный, Хотя сам уже давно перешел на libcurl. Классно  когда пришол с поиска и есть ответ.

Comment: Post всеравно не работает  std::string url = "http://poco.ua/index.php";

      Post(url);  ..
    std::string Post(std::string url)
    {

      URI uri(url.c_str());
      HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

        //Подготовить путь
       string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
        if (path.empty()) path = "/";
    HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path,

Comment: HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.setKeepAlive(true);
    req.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
    req.setContentType("text/plain");

    std::string body("Dat=Base64NumericArrayString");
    
    session.sendRequest(req) << body;

 return "";
    }

Comment: url нужно указывать так:"http: //poco.ua/index.php" (без пробела) иначе у меня возникает Net Exception. Возможно Вы так и указали, но сайт убрал. А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Пробела нет. Не работает имено пост, запускаю программу но в 1.txt ничего не пишыт.

Comment: По поводу PHP ничего сказать не могу. Никогда с ним дел не имел. У меня на другом конце порт слушает приложение написанное на С++ с использованием той же библиотеки POCO и всё работает исправно.

Comment: Попробуй отправить POST запрос из браузера, используя файл с таким содержимым:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Отправка POST-запроса</title>
   <meta charset="windows-1251">
 </head>
 <body>
   <p>   
      <form action="http://poco.ua/index.php/" method="post" enctype="text/plain">Данные: 
      <input type="text" name="Dat" value="Base64String"></form>
   </p>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Странно запрос не приходит Проблема  в части php. echo $_POST['Dat']; Буду розбираться